# How do I make firebase verify credential on the login page

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

so im making an app and the user need to create an account so I connect my app to Firebase , everything work fine on the sign up page , but on the login page I can write whatever I want and it goes to the home page ( sign in button target ) but it shouldnt cause it work even when I write invalid credential in the text field I can someone help me I know that I probably made an error but this is the code that im using

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class loginViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func SignInButton(_ sender: Any) {
    validateFields()
    }

    @IBAction func CreateOneButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SignUpPage")
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    func validateFields() {
        if Email.text?.isEmpty == true {
            print("No email text")
            return
        }
        if Password.text?.isEmpty == true {
            print("No password")
            return
        }
    login()
    }
    func login() {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: Email.text!, password: Password.text!) { [weak self] authResult, err in
            guard self != nil else {return}
            if let err = err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
            self!.checkUserInfo()
        }
    }
    func checkUserInfo() {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            print(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid as Any)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Home")
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
            present(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your login is successful but you are not sure if user logged in. You can check my answer for this question :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61229716/how-do-i-keep-a-user-logged-in-swift/61230044#61230044

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
func login() {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: Email.text!, password: Password.text!) { (results, error) in
            if error != nil {
               // sign in error (maybe display to the user)
            } else {
              // go to homescreen here
              self.goToHomeScreen()
            }
        }
    }

func goToHomeScreen() {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "Home")
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
            present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

I believe it wasn't working with your code because you are checking if the user is signed in before the .signIn() method completes, meaning it will always return nil. With the way I provided, you are first checking if there is a sign-in error (wrong credentials were entered) and if there wasn't, it will then redirect you to the Home page and you will be signed in.

Also, keep in mind that importing Firebase at the top along with FirebaseAuth is redundant. The Firebase import, encompasses all Firebase services. This means that if you're just using the authentication service in this file, you can remove the Firebase import and just leave the import for FirebaseAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue. Firebase is returning an error in the signIn function but your not handling the error and the code is falling through to `self!.checkUserInfo()`

```
func login() {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: Email.text!, password: Password.text!) { [weak self] authResult, err in
        guard self != nil else {return}
        if let err = err {
            print(err.localizedDescription) <- This prints an error
        }
        //code falls through to this next line because the error wasn't handled
        self!.checkUserInfo()
    }
}
```

Once a user is authenticated, the auth 'sticks' until they logout so this code

```
func checkUserInfo() {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
```

verifies that currentUser is not nil.

You can fix it by doing this

```
if let err = err {
   print(err.localizedDescription) <- This prints an error
   //handle the error here; present a message to the user or
   //  possibly log the prior user out
   return
}
```